# How should I apply for readmission to a graduate program from which I had to withdraw due to misconduct caused by a disability?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, health, expulsion

A few years ago, I was required to withdraw from a PhD Program at my previous institution because of academic misconduct. However, doctors found it was a result of disability. I have spent a few years publishing papers. I have also addressed the disability.

I am interested in re-applying to the same program now. The administrator told me to go through the normal admissions process again to re-apply.

I wanted to ask advice about whether this is advised. Can anyone be successful? How should one move forward?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the advice of the administrator you contacted?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, I was just curious about what the best strategy is for moving forward.

Comment: It seems like the best strategy is to follow the advice of the admins and reapply? Perhaps address your history in the Statement of Purpose. Because the alternative is to just not apply and go to a different program.

Comment: I am wondering if the history of misconduct is just so bad that I won't have a chance. Any thoughts about how to address it in a personal statement?

Comment: This is 100% dependent on the rules and preferences of the particular university.  Try it and find out.

Comment: Do you have, or can you get, letters from your doctors stating the misconduct was due to a disability that has been addressed?

Comment: Yes, I do. That's a good idea but I have that.